# sum values from selected rows

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

whenever i use sum() on a column even if i filtered the results it still sums all the values.

HERE IS MY TABLE:

```
mysql> select * from tblmedstockin where  medid = 1004;
+--------------+-------+-----------------+-------------+----------------+
| medstockinid | medid | stockinquantity | stockindate | stockinexpdate |
+--------------+-------+-----------------+-------------+----------------+
|            5 |  1004 |             147 | 2019-01-29  | 2019-01-29     |
|            6 |  1004 |              20 | 2019-01-30  | 2019-01-30     |
|           13 |  1004 |              45 | 2019-02-07  | 2019-02-07     |
+--------------+-------+-----------------+-------------+----------------+


mysql> select stockinquantity as stockinquantity from tblmedstockin where  medid = 1004 order by stockindate asc;
+-----------------+
| stockinquantity |
+-----------------+
|             147 |
|              20 |
|              45 |
+-----------------+
```

I ONLY WANT THE FIRST 2 COLUMNS TO BE SUMMED

```
mysql> select stockinquantity as stockinquantity from tblmedstockin where  medid = 1004 order by stockindate asc limit 2;
+-----------------+
| stockinquantity |
+-----------------+
|             147 |
|              20 |
+-----------------+
```

I GET THIS RESULT:

```
mysql> select sum(stockinquantity) as stockinquantity from tblmedstockin where medid = '1004' order by stockindate asc limit 2;
+-----------------+
| stockinquantity |
+-----------------+
|             212 |
+-----------------+
```

EXPECTED RESULT SHOULD BE:

```
+-----------------+
| stockinquantity |
+-----------------+
|             167 |
+-----------------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that the `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` clauses happen at the end, after the `SUM` has occurred. You need to select the data you want to sum in a subquery first, and then sum it:

```
SELECT SUM(stockinquantity) AS stockinquantity 
FROM (SELECT stockinquantity
      FROM tblmedstockin 
      WHERE medid = 1004
      ORDER BY stockindate asc
      LIMIT 2) t
```

Comment: there seems to be an error with your codeERROR 1248 (42000): Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: what does adding a 't' at the end do? that was surprising thanks

Comment: @Knuckles it is just providing a dummy table name (alias) for the output of the derived table (subquery). I chose to use `t` because it's the first letter of your table name, but you could use any valid identifier there. In more complex queries you might need to use that alias to pick between for example 2 `id` values (e.g. by writing `t.medid`)